# Responsive Layout inc HTML5 video

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm struggling with a responsive layout...

[image: What I want to achieve]
In the image above, the red is an HTML5 video & the blue are images.
I'm using JavaScript to make the HTML5 video responsive - //vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js

But however I lay this out, either Firefox, or Chrome & IE have a 1px line below images 2 & 4 (Firefox) or 5 (IE & Chrome).

See [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bw2qk6ad/1/) code here...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="col_left">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/205/"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/270/" class="has_top_margin" />
    </div>
    <div id="col_center">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="" data-setup='{"controls": false, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto"}'>
            <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/480/207/" class="has_top_margin" />
    </div>
    <div id="col_right">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/205/" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/220/270/" class="has_top_margin" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest code to make this work? I don't mind merging images 1/2 & 3/4 if it's easier... but it must be responsive & must fill the height.

EDIT: updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw2qk6ad/4/)

Comment: Show us what you have tried. HTML and CSS. Especially if there's something wrong, we can probably help you.

Comment: Damn you guys are quick - I was just adding the code...

Comment: what do you mean by having 1px line below images? Can you perhaps make a screenshot of your problem? @JezB

Comment: Heh, try to think of it beforehand. SO users can help, but you need to help us help you. :)

Comment: Yea - sorry about that. Trying to get a quick answer & didn't think my question through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Rizky!

I've 'cheated' & used a background image to get this working...

HTML

```
<div class="homepage_container">
    <img src="/images/video_background.jpg" alt="" usemap="#links_map" />
    <map name="links_map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,225,220,496" href="/link1">
        <area shape="rect" coords="740,225,960,496" href="/link2">
    </map>
    <div class="homepage_video_container">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="" data-setup='{"controls": false, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto"}'>
            <source src="videofile.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.homepage_container {position:relative}
.homepage_video_container {position:absolute; top:0; left:25%; width:50%}
```

Then, make the HTML & Imagemap responsive with plugins: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/ and https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

I hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 1):

Right, first of all, try to keep CSS and HTML seperate. Inline CSS is very confusing and will cause unwanted issues when you do use that.

> The whole point of semantic HTML and CSS is to separate document
>   structure and styling, so it just doesn’t make sense to go placing
>   styling directly in the HTML document. Remember to always keep your
>   styles in your stylesheet where they belong.

So, you should always try to have a line like the following in your `<head>` tags:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style.css">
```

For the page itself, try this:

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}

#content, #sidebar_left, #sidebar_right {
  height:500px;
}

#sr1, #sl1, #sr2, #sl2 {
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}

#sr1, #sl1 {
  height:30%;
  margin: 10px;
}

#sr2, #sl2 {
  height:70%;
  margin: 10px;
}

#c1{
  background:red;
  height:50%;
  margin:10px;
}

#c2 {
  background:blue;
  height:50%;
  margin:10px;
}

#sidebar_left {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}

#content {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
}

#sidebar_right {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="sidebar_left">
        <div id="sl1">Column 1</div>
        <div id="sl2">Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="c1">Video</div>
    <div id="c2">Column 5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar_right">
        <div id="sr1">Column 3</div>
        <div id="sr2">Column 4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JSFiddle!:**

[Here's a jsfiddle so you can play with the width.](http://jsfiddle.net/7etj8hhz/)

**EDIT:** If you are using `<img>` tags, add the following to your CSS and there will be no padding at the bottom of your images:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw2qk6ad/3/)

Comment: The supplied code was quickly extracted - I do usually separate HTML & CSS. I've updated the question with a full jsfiddle...

Comment: @JezB So then your issue is the little bit of pink that is visible at the bottom?

Comment: @JezB Check out the Edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I've added the display:block, but still get a 1px line at the bottom in some widths. I guess this is probably a rounding issue when the video is resized, but can it be overcome?

Comment: @JezB You said _In some widths_, do you mean in some widths of your browser window?